# Install teamviewer for debian 9 cli only

Tags: debian, vnc, remote-desktop, remote-management, teamviewer

Until now I used zerotier in order to reach a remote linux debian 9 machine that is a sort of vpn service, it assign you virtual router and you can add machines to it.

Something got really strange since last update of the remote client. The machine is unreacheable, I have a person there with root access that can write a small list of command but he isn't very practical so keeping the list short is better.

What list of command can I send to him in order to get a 100% sure functioning teamviewer installation so that I can get back and login in this machine ?

The machine is a full classic Debian 9 installation with NO X or anything, only CLI classic terminal.

I've read various teamviewer installation threads but every one seems to be very technical for linux, while I need something easy and unattended where the person have to do a command once, tell me his id and let me enter to fix all the mess zerotier last update leaved.

BONUS:

The command list can be also put online so he have to write a single line like a command

`runurl http:// some_pastebin_address` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this are the required steps:

```
cd /tmp
mkdir tv_install
cd tv_install
wget https://download.teamviewer.com/download/linux/teamviewer_amd64.deb
apt -y install ./teamviewer_amd64.deb
sleep 10
teamviewer --daemon restart
teamviewer passwd TestPass10
sleep 20
teamviewer info
```